# Complex initialization of variables

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a script as follows:

```
if [[ is_case1 -eq "1" ]]; then  
    VAR_A=$1  
    VAR_B=$2  
    VAR_C=$3  
    VAR_D=$4  

elif [[ is_case1 -eq "2" ]]; then   
   # initialize the variables here with specific logic 
   VAR_A=…  
    VAR_B=…  
    VAR_C=…  
    VAR_D=…  
else  
  # initialize the variables here with specific logic 
   VAR_A=…  
    VAR_B=…  
    VAR_C=…  
    VAR_D=…  
fi
```

I don’t really like this because if I have another case the initialization becomes longer and longer.
How can such cases be written more elegant?

Comment: you know bash allow `switch` statement ?

Comment: @Archemar:Yes but how is a switch solving the core issue of too many paths?

Comment: What are the different cases and what changes between them?

Comment: @Kusalananda:First case the variables are initialized from the script's params. The other cases the vars are initialized by assigning values within the if branch

Comment: Is there any reason why you do not use an array?

Comment: @Kusalananda:I don't know what you mean

Comment: Well, it look like the first branch could have `VARS=( "$@" )`, while the second branch could use `VARS=( "val1" "val2" "etc." )`.

Comment: @Kusalananda:But how is that an improvement? Could you please provide an example answer?

Comment: @Kusalananda: I don't have something against array approach. I am not sure how to use them for what I need here

Answer (score 3):

If you use an array of values rather than individual variables, initialization my be prettier:

```
#!/bin/bash

# set default values:
values=( "val1" "val2" "val3" )  # or values=()

case "$somevalue" in
    1) values=( "$@" ) ;;                    # get values from command line
    2) values=( "some" "other" "values" ) ;; # use other values
    *) # other cases uses default values
esac
```

Comment: I like it but the only thing is that the values that you are using for initializing might not really exist. This is not really equivalent to the code I pasted since the array `default` would have actual values in `case2`.

Comment: @Jim It's not easy for me to guess what `...` means in your code.

Comment: @Jim Updated to do things slightly different. I still don't know what your requirements are.

Comment: The only requirement is that the values in the vars for case 2 exist as valid values only if the condition holds true

Comment: it looks cleaner. The only change is that I need the values to be empty if it is none of the valid cases. So this `values=( "val1" "val2" "val3" )` should be something like `values=null`? or not sure how to properly express it

Comment: @Jim `values=()` would be the correct syntax.

Comment: Usually in another programming language I would create a constant to access the index of the array instead of writing VAR1=$ARRAY[1]. Is there a more readable way for this?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what problem you're trying to solve exactly, but if you wanted to have the values of the several cases encoded in an associative array of arrays (for which you need ksh93, other shells don't support arrays of arrays), in `ksh93` you could do something like:

```
#! /bin/ksh93 -
cases=(

         [1]=("$@")
         [2]=(foo 'x y' bar baz)
  [whatever]=(w x y z)
      [none]=()

)
values=(some default values)
[[ -v cases[$is_case1] ]] && values=("${cases[$is_case1][@]}")

# assign to separate variables if need be.
VAR_A=${values[0]}
VAR_B=${values[1]}
VAR_C=${values[2]}
VAR_D=${values[3]}
```

Comment: This is a very-very interesting approach! But I don't even know what is `ksh93`. Is there a way to do it that applies to bash?

Comment: @Jim, ksh93 is the shell bash copied most of its language and features from. It's a rewrite of ksh first released in 1993, while ksh was initially written in the early  80s and a subset of it (of ksh88) the basis for the POSIX sh specification (sh on most commercial Unices is based on ksh, sh on Solaris 11 is ksh93).